# Access a remote pc inside nested networks

Tags: networking, remote-desktop

One of my friend have a pc which i want to access over the internet for services like apache server.

Here the problem is that his ISP has put his entire city in a network. They didn't gave them separate IP's instead they gave them local Ips like "192.168.25.37". Which they have to set in router. Apps like team viewer or any other apps that requires p2p connection works fine but when i access his http server using his public ip it doesn't work. We even have forwarded the ports from his router. Are there any solutions?

My main goal is to use rdp and his linux apache server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the network is 'double NAT'd' which means that the IP address typed into the router only has effect within the ISP's network, and can't be used as a true public IP. And any other public IP you find will likely refer to the ISP's gateway to the broader internet.
You would need to set up port forwarding on the ISP's gateway, which of course, you can't.

Potential options:

- ask the ISP whether they give out IPv6 addresses, as this could be unique to the target PC
- ask the ISP if you can buy 'business grade' internet with a static IP for running a server - for me this costs $5/month extra
- change to an ISP that will meet your needs, talk to them before signing up if they have a useful tech support

Comment: Thank you for information. But already i knew this and i can't switch ISP as there is only one ISP in my area.I was hoping to use ddns or something like that. But i do really have to ask My ISP to give a proper public ip.